# How to find special characters using grep

Tags: linux

I want to search for characters that are not in the set [0-9] and [a-f]. Please, help me writing this regex ? I'm purely Windows user and had to deal with this stuff for specific purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a regex?  Why use grep?

```
tr -d a-f0-9 < input-file
```

Will print all the characters that fall outside the desired ranges.